# What meaning does もう add to this sentence?

Tags: nuances, adverbs, particle-しか

> これは**もう**運命としか…

Something unusual that has already happened, unexpectedly, happens again.

The character who says that is a girl who meets somebody who looks like a prince at a party and the next day she meets him once again. She is positively surprised.

The rest of the sentence should be 言いようがない or 思わない/思えない or 言わない/言えない. Because of もう, I am not sure what it means.

Comment: I would say that もう expresses annoyance more than surprise.

Comment: It's something good, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, something like 言いようがない or 思えない is omitted.

This もう is interchangeable with もはや, and they add a sense like "at this point", "now that it's reached this point", "if we've gotten this far" or "once it's come this far". It's used referring to some unexpected progression of some situation. The conclusion that follows is something extreme, and it can be very positive or very negative.

- これはもう地獄だ。
  This is now hell (already).
- もう終わりだ。
  It's over (there's no hope anymore)!
- もう最高としか<sub>(言えません)</sub>！
  (Once it's come to this, there's no other way to describe it than) This is just the best!
- こんなの笑っちゃいますよ、もう。
  I can't help but laugh at this, really.